# What does _= mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I accidentally typed this code:

```
_ = 1;
```

and I was surprised that it didn't lead to a compile error.

I checked the [C# operators docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index) and searched Stackoverflow and Google for the keywords "*_ =*" and "*underscore equals*", but to no avail.

What does this mean? Where is this used? Where can I find a reference or docs about it?

Comment: These are _discards_ See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards

Comment: If you have declared this variable before `_` is just a variable. Otherwise and if you are on .NET7 it is a `discard` as noted.

Comment: @TaW Not quite, it's not .NET7, it's C# 7